# Script to resize image only if bigger than original image

Tags: image, shell, ubuntu

I need a command line or a script in linux (ubuntu) to resize folder of images only if the image is bigger than certain size.

Example:

```
resize_command image_folder -o 500*500
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to resize all `JPEG` files in the current folder that are currently larger, down to 1600x1600, you can use `mogrify` which is part of the ImageMagick suite:

```
mogrify -resize '1600x1600>' *.jpg
```

Comment: Great answer! Didn't know about `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

files = sys.argv[1:]

for file in files:
    os.system('convert -resize 500x500\> "%s" "%s"' % (file, file))
```